# inner for query "next" not working in VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop

It cannot switch to next row and next column in the code I have stated below. That's why it cannot advance itself. Can you help me?

```vb
Sub calculate()
    Dim Column As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim startDay As String
    Dim endDay As String
    
    For Column = 2 To 350
    
        For Row = 1 To 31
        
            For i = 6 To 30
            
                If Cells(Column, Row).Value = "UI" And startDay = "" Then
             
                startDay = Cells(Row, 1).Value
                
                    Cells(i, 1).Value = startDay
             
                ElseIf Cells(Column, Row).Value = "UI" And startDay <> "" Then
                
                    endDay = Cells(1, Column).Value
                
                    Cells(i, 2).Value = endDay
                
                ElseIf Cells(Column, Row).Value <> "UI" And endDay <> "" Then
                
                    Cells(i, 2).Value = endDay
               
                End If
                
             Next i
             
        Next Row
        
    Next Column
    
End Sub
```

Comment: this code IS advancing. You aren't getting stuck in an infinite loop. Do you mean to say that it isn't doing what you want it to do? If so, you ought to check your inconsistent use of `Row` and `Columns` parameters in your `Cells` member calls.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your attention.İ tried that code but nothing change.I can not still reach next row and next column blocks so it always brings the same data.

Answer (score 0):

'Cells' accepts parameters row and column, in that order.  Please try this.

```
Sub calculate()
    Dim Column As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim startDay As String
    Dim endDay As String

    For Column = 2 To 350
        For Row = 1 To 31
            For i = 6 To 30
                If Cells(Row, Column).Value = "UI" And startDay = "" Then
                    startDay = Cells(Row, 1).Value
                    Cells(i, 1).Value = startDay
                ElseIf Cells(Row, Column).Value = "UI" And startDay <> "" Then
                    endDay = Cells(1, Column).Value
                    Cells(i, 2).Value = endDay
                ElseIf Cells(Row, Column).Value <> "UI" And endDay <> "" Then
                    Cells(i, 2).Value = endDay
                End If
             Next i
        Next Row
    Next Column
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your attention.İ tried that code but nothing change.I can not still reach next row and next column blocks